# Can RestKit receive Asynchronus responses?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, restkit

I am using RestKit to request data and perform actions using this data.

Once I have parsed the data and displayed it to the user, they can select an item to initiate playback. When the user has selected the playback the server will respond with a response code, but the server also notifies the app when the playback has finished.

e.g.

```
client                      server
request data ->
                <-respond with JSON
request_playback ->
        <-playback_started OK
        <-playback_stopped OK
```

Hope that the diagram helps out. 
I need the App to be aware of changes on the server, in this example playback started/stopped or recording started/stopped.

So basically Is there a way for RestKit to accept a response that is not initiated by a request?

Thanks for your help.

Greg.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into things like 'long polling' or 'reverse AJAX' or 'web sockets'. These are all techniques to be able to leave a connection open to the server and continuously receive responses from the server.

Maybe an alternative cleaner solution is to use Apple's push notification mechanism.

Comment: I have a mechanism on the server side that can send the msg to the app, but it almost seems that the app doesnt accept it.

Comment: What is this mechanism exactly? "Normal" http requests can't just receive responses without initiating a request. There is nothing that automatically listens to responses unless you tell it to.

Comment: After thinking about the scenario I now realise that my design is flawed. I was trying to send a response which the client had know idea about and as you mentioned this is not possible in HTTP.